# Customization of select box in html using only CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a select box that I have customized a bit using only css but I am not able to get it to function according to the requirement.

This is the complete code of the HTML page

```
<html>
<head>


<style>
select {
  -webkit-appearance:none;
  background-color:#58B14C;
  background-position:initial initial;
  background-repeat:initial initial;
  border:0;
  border-bottom-left-radius:8px;
  border-bottom-right-radius:8px;
  border-top-left-radius:8px;
  border-top-right-radius:8px;
  color:#EEEEEE;
  font-size:20px;
  font-weight:bold;
  margin-left:3px;
  padding:2px 10px;
  width:347px;
}

#mainselection { overflow:hidden; width:407px;
-moz-border-radius: 9px 9px 9px 9px;
-webkit-border-radius: 9px 9px 9px 9px;
border-radius: 9px 9px 9px 9px;
box-shadow: 1px 1px 11px #330033;
background:url("img/arrow.gif") no-repeat scroll 362px 6px black; }
</style>

</head>
<body>
<div id="mainselection">
<select>
<option>Select an Option</option>
<option>Option 1</option>
<option>Option 2</option>
</select>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

After running this code, output looks like the image I have uploaded. When I click on the green part the dropdown works like it should. I mean the way dropdown works. But I want the dropdown to come down when I click on the arrow. So is it possible that whatever decoration has been applied to background div, it can be inserted in the select's css. along with the image? Or any javascript that can be written to get the desired functionality?
[image]

Comment: Have you tried applying the background to the select box itself and not the parent container?

Comment: @Kai Qing Yea but then how would I apply multiple color backgrounds to the select box. I want the the appearance to look lik the image.

Comment: You can not open select box by clicking outside. http://solidlystated.com/scripting/open-select-box-with-javascript/

Comment: @Sree Its ok. I got it working in a different way. But yeah its true you cannot open select box using javascript unless you have written it yourself.